# IF two criteria are met then copy certain column to another sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm new to VBA :', I wonder if I could use the If AND function within VBA. When columns C and D are filled with values, VBA will automatically copy columns A, B, and E and paste them to another sheet. Plus if it is possible i want to make it dynamic.

For example, I have this table in Sheet1:

| Name | Phone# | Class | Graduated | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ariana | 749142 | 9 | Yes | 3.6 |
| Brian | 454364 |  |  | 3.7 |
| Harry | 143246 | 12 | Yes | 4 |
| Mady | 356647 | 10 |  | 2.9 |

Columns C and D need to have a value inside both cells, then VBA will copy columns A, B, and E to columns A, B, and C in Sheet2.

However, VBA will do nothing with the row if:

- only one column has value (e.g. row 5)
- both columns have no value (e.g. row 3)

I hope it make sense :)

Comment: Have you started with something like `Range("$A$1:$E$5").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"`?

Comment: sorry I'm new to VBA I'm not familiar with that. Could you please explain? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on Sheet1 tab > `View Code` > paste code into sheet1 module

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Intersect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CountLarge property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144247)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:D")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If .CountLarge = 1 Then
                Dim iR As Long: iR = .Row
                If Len(Me.Cells(iR, "C")) > 0 And Len(Me.Cells(iR, "D")) > 0 Then
                    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
                    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
                    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    If Len(oSht.Cells(lastRow, 1)) > 0 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
                    oSht.Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                        Array(Me.Cells(iR, "A"), Me.Cells(iR, "B"), Me.Cells(iR, "E"))
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Update:

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 2)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 3)) * Len(arrData(i, 4)) > 0 Then
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 5)
        End If
    Next i
    If iR > 0 Then
        oSht2.Cells.Clear
        oSht2.Range("A1").Resize(iR, 3).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code doesn't give any result. I think I prefer using button than worksheet changes. But, thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Please make sure the code is stored in `sheet1 module` instead of `standard module`.

Comment: Of course, you could use a button too. Pls try the updated code.